# How to replicate the functionality of `strtod`, etc. without getting the warning "Assigning to 'char *' from 'const char *' discards qualifier"?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, c99

There are many posts about this particular warning, but I wasn't able to find one that specifically references a function signature like that of `strtod` and friends.

I have a function `int foo(const char *str, char **end)`, and there's no way that I have discovered to set `*end = str` before returning the integer without encountering the aforementioned warning. Is there some additional qualifier that I'm leaving out, or is it something I'm going to have to "live with"?

Comment: Is there any reason why `end` can't be a `const char**`?

Comment: Note you can declare, and the standard could have declared (new functions; the old ones were already in use when `const` was added) the function as `int foo(const char *str, ptrdiff_t *distance)`. Then the caller gets a distance from the start to the end character, and they simply add it to their start to get the end. That works both for callers parsing a `const char` string and those parsing a `char` string. E.g., the caller would do `ptrdiff_t distance; int result = foo(string, &distance); char *end = string + distance;`.

Comment: My answer shows how to do it with a cast in a way that is fully defined by the standard. However, if you wished to avoid a cast, an uglier but still defined way is `memcpy(end, &str, sizeof *end);`. That is defined because C 2018 6.2.5 28 says pointers to qualified and unqualified versions of the same type (or compatible types) have the same representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly, this is actually a big fat wart in the modern C Standard.  It's impossible to implement `strtod` without an explicit cast.  There was a huge amount of discussion about this, back in the day, with radical proposals being made for bizarre extensions to the language to make it possible to write `strtod` "correctly".  But the cures were all worse than the disease, so in the end, the radical proposals were not adopted, and the result it that it's tricky (but not impossible) to write `strtod` and the like.

In your implementation, you will typically have a pointer `p` that points to the first character you didn't parse.  Since `p`'s initial value was your input string, which was `const char *`, your `p` will typically be a `const char *`, too.  (And this is fine, because you don't intend to use `p` to modify the string as you parse it.)  But when it comes time to set `endp`, you're simply going to have to use a cast:

```
*endp = (char *)p;
```

It feels lousy to be "casting away constness" like this, but it's really the only way, and it's actually perfectly legal, as Eric P. explains in [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68340938/how-to-replicate-the-functionality-of-strtod-etc-without-getting-the-warning/68341204#68341204).

(Another possibility is `*(const char **)endp = p;`, but it's more typing, even more sketchy-looking, and it turns out not strictly legal.)

Normally the rule is that explicit casts like this are poor form.  Normally the recommendation is to find a way to not need the explicit cast.  And although the general rule is a good one, this is an exception, pure and simple.  Based on everything else that's going on, the conclusion is that you need this cast here, and if you try to get by without it, you end up having to do something even worse elsewhere.

In answer to a question in a comment, the reason we can't make `endp` be a `const char **` is that it makes things too inconvenient on the caller.  The caller might be using pointers that are not `const`-qualified.  Now, if the caller has

```
char *str = "123.456xyz";
```

and then calls

```
double d = strtod(str, NULL);
```

this is fine: it's okay to pass a regular `char *` to a function that expects `const char *`.  But if the caller wants to get the end pointer back, and additionally declares

```
char *endp;
```

and then calls

```
double d = strtod(str, &endp);
```

and if `strtod` were declared as

```
double strtod(const char *, const char **);
```

it turns out it wouldn't work.  You can pass a `char *` to a function that expects a `const char *`, but you can *not* pass a `char **` to an function that expects a `const char **`.  The explanation for why you can't is rather obscure.  There's a sort-of-coherent explanation in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html).

Comment: `*(const char **)endp = p;` violates the aliasing rule in C 2018 6.5 7, so its behavior is not defined by the C standard. `*endp = (char *) p;` is defined by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks.  I don't remember why I used that cumbersome cast in the particular piece of old code I cribbed from for this post.  You're right, the simpler cast is much better.  Post edited.

Comment: The part about casting a `char **` to a `const char **` is interesting. It seems like the problem outlined in the FAQ would be solved by implementing `const`-ness into the language differently.

Answer (score 2):

> … there's no way that I have discovered to set `*end = str`…

Simply use `*end = (char *) str;`. When you explicitly convert using a cast, the compiler will not warn you. Further, this is fully defined by the C standard.

C 2018 6.3.2.3 7 says a pointer to an object type (here `str`) may be converted to a pointer to a different object type (here `char *`). If the resulting pointer were not correctly aligned for the new type, the behavior would be undefined. However, any pointer is correctly aligned for `char`, so that is fine. That paragraph also  tells us that when we convert a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. And that is just what we have done, convert to a pointer to a character type.

These rules do not prohibit us from removing `const` in the cast: Converting from the `const char *` that is `str` to `char *` is allowed. (A different rule says the behavior is undefined if an attempted is made to modify an object defined with `const`, but we are not going to do that. Just pointing to it without `const` is fine.)

Then the caller gets this pointer back in their `end` object. It is a valid pointer to the byte that ended the parse. So they can use it. If they are working with a string defined without `const`, they can use this `end` pointer to read and/or write to the string. If they are working with a string defined with `const`, they can use this `end` pointer to read from the string, and they are also free to convert it to a `const char *`.